# Matlab 2-dim Fourier Transformation with different exponent

Tags: matlab, matrix, 2d, fft

I have no idea how i could explain the problem correctly.

I have a matrix which corresponds to a 2D cartesian system. Now i have to do a Fouriertransformation, but the exp-function doesnt have the form exp(-i(ux+vy)) but exp(-iA(ux+vy). 
Where A is a constant in the range of 10^15 and my input matrix ranges from 0 to 10.

The exact Formula I want to program is:
matrix(u,v) = integral integral matrix(x,y) exp(-iA(ux+vy))dx dy

The only solution I see so far is to use the integral2 Function with a function which expects 2 parameters (x,y) and a handle to u,v.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is the `A` in the exponent you just have to do a variable transformation.
Then the integral you have to calculate is

```
     matrix(u,v) = A^-2 integral integral matrix(x,y) exp(-i(ux+vy))dx dy
```

Doing this, you then can just use `fft2`:

```
    M_uv = A^-2 * fft2(M_xy)
```

where `M_xy` is your matrix(x,y) and `M_uv` then would be the resulting Fourier transform matrix(u,v).

Comment: You are right, that with a variable transformation the problem is avoided, but if i am not mistaken a new problem is created. If My matrix is defined only for lets say 1 to 1000 then the integral would be zero outside of this range and only add to the result inside this range. With the variable trans. my new Matrix would look like (X'/A,Y'/A) and the nonzero integral would go from A to x_max times A. So i get instead of A Elements x_max'*A elements which should be computed but my matrix doesnt have those elements.

How is matlab going to handle the interelemental parts of the integral?

Comment: Don't know if i was able to explain this new problem right.
For the matrix element to be addressed correctly in the integral the new x and y have to jump in steps of A but the integrals dont do that.

Alternatively my resulting matrix could be size(M_xy)*A but that ain't what i am looking for either